# Node js db.auth.find() is not a function

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB as a database for my website, and as a collection for authentication of users, I created a collection named "auth". The problem now is that I want to show database content in my shell but I can't use `db.auth.find()` because there is a built-in function with this name [db.auth()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.auth/).

So, when I try that I get the following error:

> E QUERY [js] uncaught exception: TypeError: db.auth.find is not a function :
> @(shell):1:1

Is there any way to show the collection content, or to rename it if it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like you aren't calling find on the collection,

for instance- in mongo if I had a collection named 'auth' I would need to do:

```
db.getCollection('auth').find({})
```

or for a fuller example in node.js that just connects to a local mongo, with a db named `users`, that has a collection named `auth` and prints the documents..
you should change this to your own logic of course :)

```
 const uri = `mongodb://localhost:27017`;
 const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true , useUnifiedTopology: true });
 client.connect(err => {
    const tasksCollection = client.db("users").collection("auth");
    tasksCollection.find({}).toArray( ( err, documents) => {
        console.log(documents);
    })
 })
```

but of you still want to rename the collection:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.renameCollection/